# Removing onclick function from this code

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am actually unsure how to title this question so apologies if the title doesnt help much.

Basically I have the following function of code (not mine).

```
function expandElement(container, before, afterLength, animate) {
    if(animate == undefined) animate = true;
    if(animate) container.childElements().each(function (x) { Effect.SlideUp(x); });
    var nextTokens = getNextTokens(before, afterLength);
    var holderDiv = document.createElement('div');
    nextTokens.each(function(token) {
        var newBefore = before + token[1];
        var newAfter = afterLength - token[0].length;
        var newHTML = '<div><div><a href="#" onclick="Effect.SlideUp(this.up(\'div\'), {duration: 0.25}); return false">[x]</a> ' + newBefore.escapeHTML() + (newAfter > 0 ? '<a href="#" onclick="expandElement(this.up(\'div\', 1), &quot;' + newBefore.escapeHTML() + '&quot;, ' + newAfter + '); return false">' + input.substr(input.length - newAfter).escapeHTML() + '</a>' : '') + '</div></div>';
        var newElement = holderDiv.insert({bottom: newHTML});
    });

    container.insert({ bottom: holderDiv });
    if(animate) {
        holderDiv.hide();
        Effect.BlindDown(holderDiv);
    }
}
```

The original coder has designed it so that you have to click on the next part of the "token" and then it will reveal it. as seen on the line starting:

"var newHTML = '....."

However I want to take this functionality away and just display all possible tokens from the start.

Can anyone provide any assistance on this?

Regards,

jmcall10

Comment: Downvoted? If you are gonna downvote then at least respond why!

Comment: Likely voted down for not providing a [mcve] - SO is not a conversion service but if you ask such a question at least provide enough information - such as what is the Effect library and what are container, before, afterLength, animate

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove onclick attributes. so try to change like this :

```
...
var newHTML = '<div><div><a href="#">[x]</a> ' + newBefore.escapeHTML() + (newAfter > 0 ? '<a href="#">' + input.substr(input.length - newAfter).escapeHTML() + '</a>' : '') + '</div></div>';
...
```

and check if it works as you want or not. if not let me know.

remember to complete refresh {"CTRL+F5"} on browser after updating js or other static files

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I see what you are saying however maybe I did not explain myself correctly. I still want the function that the onclick calls to run but just without the user having to click it. Regards, jmcall10

Comment: I was thinking of rewriting the code, but some data is missing completely. for example there is no information about arguments and function "getNextTokens" . You need to put all needed codes and ask a new question.